# Flutter cannot display local files using webview

Tags: android, flutter, webview, flutterwebviewplugin, webview-flutter

I am trying to display local files using webview (if there is other option, it is welcomed, but I am trying to display not just pdf. I want to display pdf,xlsx,docx).

I am suppliying url with `file://...`, first it gived me access denied error with both `flutter_webview_plugin` and `webview_flutter` plugin. then I edited the source code of both of plugins and congiured `setAllowFileAccessFromFileURLs` as true according to [this](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebSettings#setAllowFileAccessFromFileURLs(boolean)) reference but this time it just shows white blank page to me. And there is strange warning in the console (this warning was shown even before I edit the source code.)

warning:

`W/m.packagename(31636): Couldn't lock the profile file /data/user/0/packagename/app_tbs_64/core_share/oat/tbs_sdk_extension_dex.jar.cur.prof: Failed to open file '/data/user/0/packagename/app_tbs_64/core_share/oat/tbs_sdk_extension_dex.jar.cur.prof': No such file or directory W/m.gekapp.gekap(31636): Could not forcefully load profile /data/user/0/packagename/app_tbs_64/core_share/oat/tbs_sdk_extension_dex.jar.cur.prof`

I am using Android 11 on the phone I think that might be the issue. (There is no problem on the iOS I can display the files using `file://...`)

`flutter doctor --verbose`

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.2.0, on macOS 11.3 20E232 darwin-arm, locale en-TR)
    • Flutter version 2.2.0 at /Users/burakcabadan/development/flutter
    • Framework revision b22742018b (4 weeks ago), 2021-05-14 19:12:57 -0700
    • Engine revision a9d88a4d18
    • Dart version 2.13.0

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.3)
    • Android SDK at /Users/burakcabadan/Library/Android/sdk
    • Platform android-30, build-tools 30.0.3
    • Java binary at: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b3-6915495)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS
    • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    • Xcode 12.5, Build version 12E262
    • CocoaPods version 1.10.1

[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome

[✓] Android Studio (version 4.1)
    • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b3-6915495)

[✓] IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate Edition (version 2021.1)
    • IntelliJ at /Applications/IntelliJ IDEA.app
    • Flutter plugin version 55.1.5
    • Dart plugin version 211.7233

[✓] VS Code (version 1.56.2)
    • VS Code at /Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents
    • Flutter extension version 3.23.0

[✓] Connected device (2 available)
    • macOS (desktop) • macos  • darwin-arm64   • macOS 11.3 20E232 darwin-arm
    • Chrome (web)    • chrome • web-javascript • Google Chrome 91.0.4472.77

• No issues found!
```

Comment: Did you set minSdkVersion as 19 in android/app/build.gradle?

https://pub.dev/packages/webview_flutter

Comment: Can you please share `flutter doctor --verbose`?

Comment: Yes I set it to 19. I am adding verbose output

Comment: If it works on iOS but not on Android, then it might be related to your AndroidManifest.xml. 

Please check it too:
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

Comment: I do not think it is because that permission because it has nothing to do with internet connection

Comment: I tried and still the same.

Comment: Did you fix it? Today I was faced with the same issue!